# How to toggle a class using ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I know you can easily toggle a class like this:

```css
.c {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #00adff;
}

.a {
  background: #43dd31;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <div class="c" ng-class="{'a': toggle }">
    <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is, what if I have two separate classes I want to toggle with different buttons on the same `div` using this method?

Comment: _... what if I have two separate classes I want toggle with different buttons on the same div using this method..._ I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you mean. Can you explain a bit more. maybe specify this  use case in more detail.

Comment: @31piy already provided the answer I was looking for and there is hardly a need for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS allows you to define numerous classes in the map-format. Following is a demo to toggle a class `b` using a second button.

```css
.c {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #00adff;
}

.a {
  background: #43dd31;
}

.b {
  border: 5px dashed yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <div class="c" ng-class="{'a': toggle, b: secondToggle}">
    <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle</button>
    <button ng-click="secondToggle = !secondToggle">Second Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```